# Display array occurrences by date in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, date

I'm looking to iterate through a JSON array, to find the occurrences of a given item by date. To illustrate, I have the following JSON:

```
"data": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "hello",
        "world",
        "alice"
      ],
      "date": [
        1402876800000
      ],
      ...
    },
    {
      "tags": [
        "foo",
        "world",
        "alice"
      ],
      "date": [
        1402963200000
      ],
      ...
    }
```

What I want to do is be able to call a function which takes an input of the tag ('foo', for example), and writes into the HTML how many times that tag occurs on a particular date. So calling `tagOverTime('foo')` would result in something like this:

06/16/14 - 14 occurrences

06/17/14 - 8 occurrences

I would also like to format the date, but I'm confident I can do this at some point myself with `toLocaleDateString()`. As it stands, I'm able to iterate through the array, but not much else. This is what I have so far:

```
$.getJSON('mydata.json', function(data) {

function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

function tagOverTime(tagtosearch) {
  var output="<h4>" + tagtosearch + "</h4><ul>";
    for(var i = 0 ; i< data.data.length; i++){
        var obj = data.data[i];
        var tagsArray = obj["tags"];
          // make sure tag array isn't empty
          if( tagsArray != undefined ) {
          // then iterate through it
          for(var j = 0; j < tagsArray.length;j++ ){
            // if that tag exists in the given tags array, check its date and count up somehow
            if(tagsArray[j] == tagtosearch){
              output+='<li>' + obj.date + '</li>';
            }
          }
        }
    }
  output+="</ul>";
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=output;
}

tagOverTime('foo');
```

But I know this isn't right because it just outputs an unordered list of the dates; I was aware of that as I wrote the code, but wasn't sure about how to go about counting up particular dates.

Comment: FYI, `containsObj` is the same as `$.inArray(obj, list) != -1`

Comment: Make an object whose properties are the dates. Loop over your data, and increment the counter in the property with that date. When it's done, the object contains the totals you want.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that? I understand declaring a new object, but not necessarily how to populate it with the data from another array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tagOverTime(tagToSearch) {
    var output="<h4>" + tagtosearch + "</h4><ul>";
    var byDate = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data.data[i];
        var tagsArray = obj.tags;
        if (tagsArray && containsObject(tagToSearch, tagsArray) {
            if (byDate[obj.date]) { // Have we already seen this date?
                byDate[obj.date]++;
            } else { // No, initialize it to 1
                byDate[obj.date] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for (var date in byDate) {
        output += '<li>' + date + ' - ' + byDate[date] + ' occurrences</li>';
    }
    output += '</ul>';
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=output;
}
```